# Successful log into Azure AD results in Request.IsAuthenticated equalling 'false' with .NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

I am encountering the following strange behaviours when logging into Azure AD via my .NET application.
The code for implementing Azure AD login has been taken essentially verbatim from [here](https://www.codeguru.com/azure/mvc-web-apps-azure/)

- When running the application and clicking on the "sign in" link, i proceed to log into the Microsoft interface. upon successful login (i assume), it redirects to my action controller where i then check `Request.IsAuthenticated`. This field evaluates to false. Why would this be so?
- If i stop debugging the application, then re-run it, somehow clicking on the sign-in link will **skip** the Microsoft login page and proceed to show the logged in page. It even populates `userClaims.FindFirst("name").Value`

What seems to be a straightforward process has left me head scratching.

Additionally, in web.config, the "authentication" tag has been totally removed

Furthermore, the "sign in" link, that triggers the below code seems to create a new OpenIDconnect cookie each time?

```
 public void SignIn()
    {
        if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext()
                .Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
                    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Have you checked if the web.config  has redirectUri added and also in the startup. and change  or comment out <authentication mode="forms" /> in web.config file

Comment: @kavyaS I have removed that all together. It's a very strange issue

Comment: After Sign-in from Azure AD, do you see the ASP.NET Sign-in cookies generated?

Comment: @SatishYadav where can I find those?

Comment: Chrome/Edge Dev Tools -> Applications -> Cookies. Same place as your screenshot in the question .

Comment: One thing I noticed, in your Challenge method call, the                   RedirectUrl is "/". After sing-in Identity Provider will redirect the request with authentication result (Claims/Identity) to your Redirect URI. Are you handling that?

Comment: In Azure App Registration's Authentication; 1. Do you have ID tokens and/or Access Tokens checked?  2. Do you have your localhost URI (with port) in the list of Redirect URIs?

Comment: @SatishYadav the ASP.NET cookies does not get generated when the redirectURL is called. However, if i stop debugging the application  and re-run it, click the sign in link, the cookie gets generated (see point 2 of my question)

Comment: @LarryDukek yes and yes

Answer (score 0):

Successful log into Azure AD results in Request.IsAuthenticated equalling 'false' with .NET MVC

> Successful log into Azure AD results in Request.IsAuthenticated equalling ‘false’ with .NET MVC

I have followed the below steps and able to get the `IsAuthenticated` value as true.

- Created MVC Application with `Microsoft Identity Platform Authentication`.

[image]

- No need to go to Azure Active Directory and register app from there.
- Once the Application is created, you will get an option to create Microsoft Identity platform.
- If you have app registered already, select that or create one new.

[image]

- No need to add any code, the above step will does every thing for you.
- Just verify the settings in `web.config` file.

After Authentication,you can see the `IsAuthenticated` value is `true`.

***Request.IsAuthenticated***

[image]

[image]

***!Request.IsAuthenticated***
[image]

> the “sign in” link, that triggers the below code seems to create a new OpenIDconnect cookie each time?

Thanks @Satish Yadav for the comment.

When I check the Cookies option, I don`t see any new OpenIDconnect created.

[image]

The only difference I found with your code is after `Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()`.

***My default `Startup.Auth.cs` code:***

```cs
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = authority,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,

            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
            {
                SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
                {
                    string name = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("preferred_username").Value;
                    context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, name, string.Empty));
                    return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        });                 
}
```